# How can I update my project version numbers using Git?

Tags: git, automation, githooks, version-numbering

Say I have two branches: `develop` and `feature`.

Assume I also have a file called `VersionNumber` which has the following content:

> BUILD_NUMBER 1

I want to use Git hooks so that, when I merge `feature` into `develop`, the `BUILD_NUMBER` field gets incremented automatically.

I thought about the following process using the `post-merge` hook:

1. Check that branch being merged into is `develop`
2. Update the `VersionNumber` file by incrementing `BUILD_NUMBER` by 1
3. Add the updated file: `git add VersionNumber`
4. Amend the commit: `git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify`

It all works fine until the final command. Git says I can't amend the commit in the middle of a merge (which is surprising to me, since I thought this was `post-merge`).

Any advice on how I can do this (using `post-merge` or any other hook for that matter)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question lacks code example. However I was able to reproduce for the fun of it.
Indeed you can not amend things (such as a change to a file) to a merge commit - this seems to make some sense. Indeed you are post-merge but by using `amend` you try to go back into the merge commit and modify it.

So best chance you have, I think, is to simply add a commit for the version bump.

Anything else would just make it horribly complicated and prone to corner-cases that don't work and cost you lots of time figuring out how to salvage your commits and versioning. I always like to keep things as simple as posible. But maybe someone else can come up with something better.

This is the `post-merge` hook I wrote, if anyone is interested; does not check for the branch:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d+)/1+$1/e' VersionNumber 
echo "bump version: `cat VersionNumber`"
git add VersionNumber
git commit --amend -m "bump version: `cat VersionNumber`"
```